# mysql insert unique values from one column to a column of another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

please help me in this matter: I need to copy the unique values from *entries_list.nr_comanda_entries* to *entries_uploaded.ship_id*.

The tables have these values in common: *entries_list.file_id = entries_uploaded.id*

Both tables have many other columns, only the *entries_uploaded.ship_id* is empty.

Could you please tell me the mysql query to do that?

Comment: This question appears to lack basic research

Comment: Maybe it appears so, but believe me I'm a beginner and didn't know what to look for.

Comment: I'd have googled "MySQL for beginners". That would probably do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an UPDATE query and an INNER JOIN:

```
UPDATE
  entries_uploaded INNER JOIN entries_list
  ON entries_list.file_id = entries_uploaded.id
SET
  entries_uploaded.ship_id = entries_list.nr_comanda_entries
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/70315/1).